# How to fix login issue while connecting sql server management studio. Error is : No process is on the other end of the pipe (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When trying to Connect with Database Engine with the help of SQL Server 2014 Management Studio at that time i am getting error.A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.No process is on the other end of the pipe. Microsoft SQL Server Error: 233.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Possible duplicate of [No process is on the other end of the pipe (SQL Server 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267658/no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe-sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 0):

Steps are as: 
a.) Open Registry Editor. With help of pressing Window+R key you can search regedit. 
b.) Then follow Path as :
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
c.) Then delete all Protocols under Protocols option.
d.) Then you could restart your SQL Service and reopen the SQL Studio(SSMS).And try to connect.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on 2014, and I had created a user, gave it permissions, everything looked great.  I reopened SQL Server Management Studio 2014, attempted to logon as that user, and got the "...end of the pipe" error as you did.

In the end, all I needed to do, after making all my changes and modifications for my database and SQL Server, was to **restart the service**.

[image]